# Why are those Meshes darker in this direction?

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv, faces

As seen on the picture, even if all the different meshes use the same texture, they appear to be darker than the others (on the basic wall for example). But this only is the case on that one side, as you can see on the right in the image. I've checked the normals, they are turned in the right direction.. What else could it be?
The problem exists in viewport and rendered view.
thanks in advance

Download blendfile + Brick Texture: https://www.mediafire.com/file/q35j2jmp6pk5dr8/Library%252BTexture.zip/file

[image: The red circled parts are obviously darker than the other parts around, but everything is fine on the x-axis (as you can see in the right)]

Comment: The image you show in you question is from the 3D Viewport, Material Preview. Does this darken effect happen as well in the rendered view and rendered image?

Comment: Hello, maybe pack your image and share your file (or at least 2 wall, one with the darker texture): https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots, I have added a downloadlink to the description of my question

Comment: @WolfiG, yes the problem too appears in the rendered view and in rendered images.

Comment: Note there's a scale mismatch, as the bricks on the highlighted area are much larger than the bricks on the rest of the wall.  This could also affect the tone of things, as you're getting more texture detail on the bricks that might be aliased out on the smaller ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the normal map to *Non-Color* (not sure why it didn't give the same result on both the 2 objects though). Also recalculate the normals.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the Job for me ^^